# click won't trigger jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `link_to '#'` inside a `div` which should trigger fading in a form, on click.

```
<div id="atendees-wrap">

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :atendees do |a| %>

    <div class="expandable-members">
      <%= link_to 'Membrul', '#', class: 'trigger' %>  
    </div>

    <div id="primary-info"></div>
    <div id="secondary-info"></div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

The problem is, it won't event enter the function.
Here's the js code:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#atendees-wrap').find('.expandable-members').click(function() {
    debugger
    $('#primary-info, #secondary-info').fadeIn("slow");
  });

})
```

Same goes for:

```
$('input[name*="agree"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log( "clicked" );
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

I tried with `mouseup` and `on("click", function(){})` but same result.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you included jquery.js? Checked the console for any errors?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yep, no errors and jquery is included. I have 2 other functions which work just fine.

Comment: Have you checked the length of $('#atendees-wrap').find('.expandable-members'), does it find anything?

Comment: @Alex.Me you are right, the element was being added after dom load.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. Use `'javascript:;'` instead of '#' for href.

```
<div id="atendees-wrap">

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :atendees do |a| %>

    <div class="expandable-members">
      <%= link_to 'Membrul', 'javascript:;', class: 'trigger' %>  
    </div>

    <div id="primary-info"></div>
    <div id="secondary-info"></div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

And

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#atendees-wrap .expandable-members').click(function() {
    $('#primary-info, #secondary-info').fadeIn("slow");
  });

})
```

Also I am unable to find input tag matching this selector this selector `$('input[name*="agree"]')` in the code that you posted

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#atendees-wrap .expandable-members', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('#primary-info, #secondary-info').slideToggle("slow");
});
```